# The argument type 'UserModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<UserData>'

Tags: flutter, dart

this is mycode .please solve this problem

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:internetconnectivityusingbloc/repos/user_model.dart';

class UserRepositories {
  Future<void> getUsers() async {
    List<UserData>? userData = [];
    String urlEndPoint = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

    // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
    Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlEndPoint));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      userData = [];
      // final List result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return userData.addAll(UserModel.fromjson(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
      // print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }
}
```

i am trying to solve this problem .but i am failed.so i expecting u are solve this problem

Comment: you are getting this error cause you are trying to add UserModel data to UserData type list

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` inside addAll:

```
return userData.addAll([UserModel.fromjson(response.body)]);
```

If you are only adding one model is better to only use the method add.

Howerver you are trying to add a type `UserModel` to a list of `UserData` and that might throw another error if `UserModel` is not a child of `UserData`. So if you are expecting to fill the variable `userData` you should use `UserData.fromjson(response.body)` to fill the new data, so you should adjust UserData parameters to get the data that response.body will bring.